# Getting value of list of checkboxes using thymeleaf, spring boot

Tags: java, checkbox, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here, i have a form which have list of user with checkboxes. I need to get boolean values as well as user ids of respective checkboxes to know the boolean value whether true or false for each user to insert values as per user in the database.
For Example:

[image]

Let's say we have three users of id 1,2,3 then i need the checkbox checked value like 1,0,1 for respective user. So, as to insert boolean value for the user if checked or not.

<-- main.html -->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en" th:include="fragments/header :: header">
</head>
<body>
    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/navigation :: navigation"></div>

    <div class="container" id="attendanceDiv">
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"
            th:if="${error} == 'false'" th:text="${message}"></div>

        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"
            th:if="${error} == 'true'" th:text="${message}"></div>

        <h3>Add</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <form id="attendanceform" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" role="form"
            th:action="@{/attendance/createall}" method="post">
            <div class="checkbox" th:each="users : ${users}">
                <label> 
                    <input type="checkbox" id="present" name="present"
                    th:text="${users.firstname} + ' ' + ${users.lastname}"></input> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="user" name="user" th:value="${users.id}" />
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div lang="en" th:include="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me i don't know how to get input data for multiple checkboxes and i am using spring boot, spring data jpa with thymeleaf.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First at all, your checkbox must have a value field. In the java method to process this form, should be like:

```
@RequestMapping("/attendance/createall")
public ResponseEntity<String> foo(@RequestParam("present") List<String> values) {

    //.....
}
```

Comment: I can get only one value but how can i get list of users and boolean value from the form?

Comment: It's missing the value in your input. `<input type="checkbox" id="present" name="present"
                    th:text="${users.firstname} + ' ' + ${users.lastname}" th:value="${user.id}"></input> ` or any other field you want to use as identifier

Comment: Thank you so much @sigrist and one thing how to get value of check boxes whether true or false. For example: true for Test Test, false for t t and true for Po Po.

Comment: As you get a list of values, a simple `values.contains('Po')` should work

Comment: No i meant from the list of values i have to check if values are true or false. I want true for checked values and false for the unchecked values. For example Test Test = true, t t = false and Po Po = true.